# How do you avoid lots of [FromService] parameters with ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project that uses lots of dependency injection.

The problem is that these start to stack up on my controller actions:

```
public async Task LoginAsync(
    [FromBody] LoginModel login,
    [FromServices] IConnectionMultiplexer redis,
    [FromServices] ISerialiserFactory serialiser,
    [FromServices] IDataService dataService,
    [FromServices] ILookupNormalizer normaliser,
    [FromServices] IPasswordHasher hasher,
    ...
```

I can put these in the constructor, but most methods don't use them and those that do don't always use all of them.

I can directly instantiate them, but then I lose the ability to inject them in the startup.

Is there an easier way to get at these injected services? Ideally I want to call something like:

```
// It turns out I need the injected serialiser
var serialiser = services.Get<ISerialiserFactory>();
```

Is there a way to do this already in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: if most of the methods don't use these dependencies, maybe it worth to split your controller into two controllers?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy quite possibly, but that results in most of my controllers being split for the corner case (maybe 1% of requests) when all these services are needed.

Comment: @Keith: How about reconsider your software design? If you need services like `IPasswordHasher` inside an action, it means your abstraction sucks. Controller and actions should only coordinate and not perform any business logic! Refactor your Login method into a service, inject the dependencies into your new service and inject the **ONE** service into your action/controller. This blog post may be useful from Mark Seemann who as written a comprehensive book about DI already ;) http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/ or check his answers here on SO

Comment: Also don't use `var serialiser = services.Get<ISerialiserFactory>();`, it is a service locator pattern and an anti-pattern. Hard to test/mock

Comment: @Tseng yes, `LoginAsync` calls the methods that actually contain the business logic - a new service is what I really want, but it needs some services that are singleton and others that exist for the duration of the action. That's why I'm sure these stacks of [FromService] parameters are wrong, but it's not at all clear how to get these through the business logic.

Comment: Don't use static singletons. Using singletons within DI is fine (´services.AddSingleton<IMyService,MyService>()`). If you use DI, you have to use it **all the way**. I still don't see any reason to inject so many services in your action. Maybe show the complete code of your action, sure it can be abstracted in a new service

Comment: @Tseng I mean that some of these are `services.AddSingleton` and others are `services.AddScoped` and others are `services.AddTransient`. The BL code that consumes these services is not itself a service, and it isn't immediately obvious how to instantiate it so that it can consume the other services of varying duration.

Comment: You **do not instantiate classes services** when you use DI!!! A service should never be instantiated with `new` when using DI or you did it wrong. Only exceptions are factories and during unit tests, where you instantiate the class under test via `new`. I'll post an answer soon show it in an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, if you have so many dependencies in a single controller action it, its a very good sign of badly abstracted code: Your controller is doing more than it should.

Ideally, the controller action should be just a few lines of code per action (rule of thumb, 10-15 lines of code). If you have more, you are probably doing to much inside it.

A controller action should only accept the input from user (form or WebApi-esque), validate it and delegate it to a service as well as handling http status codes.

i.e.

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    public IConnectionMultiplexer redis,
    public ISerialiserFactory serialiser,
    public IDataService dataService,
    public ILookupNormalizer normaliser,
    public IPasswordHasher hasher

    public LoginService(/* inject your services here */) 
    {
        
    }

    public async Task<bool> Login(LoginModel login) 
    {
        // Do your logic here and perform the login

        return /*true or false*/;
    }
}
```

Then inject this into your controller or your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody]LoginModel login, [FromServices]ILoginService loginService) 
{
    // Validate input, only rough validation. No business validation here
    if(!Model.IsValid) 
    {
        return BadRequest(Model);
    }

    bool success = await loginService.Login(model);

    if(success) 
    {
        return RedirectTo("Login");
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}
```

If you get more code than that, it's a code smell. Especially if you do some logic etc. Your controllers should be as thin as possible. Controllers are rather hard to test (compared to `ILoginService` in my example).

You should never have to call `new LoginService(...)` at any time (except, if you create an abstract factory).

Also you should always prefer to use constructor injection. Use `[FromServices]` only, when the services is required in one single action. If its required in multiple actions, always use constructor injection

```
public LoginController : Controller
{
    public ILoginService loginService;

    public LoginController(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        if(loginService==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loginService));

        this.loginService = loginService
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody]LoginModel login)
    {
        // Do your stuff from above
        ...
        bool success = await loginService.Login(login);
        ...
    }
}
```

It's also no problem, if the dependencies have different lifetimes, as long as the lifetime of the main object is shorter than of it's dependencies.

i.e. if your one of the above dependencies is scoped, then your `ILoginService` must be scoped too. It will be disposed at the end of the request.

```
services.AddSingleton<ISerialiserFactory, ...>();
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer, ...>();
services.AddScoped<IDataService, ...>();
services.AddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, ...>();
services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher, ...>();
services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
```

That will work fine.

```
services.AddSingleton<ISerialiserFactory, ...>();
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer, ...>();
services.AddScoped<IDataService, ...>();
services.AddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, ...>();
services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher, ...>();

// This will create trouble
services.AddSingleton<ILoginService, LoginService>();
```

But this won't. Now, ILoginService will be singleton, but it's dependencies will get disposed after the first request. Subsequent request will trigger an exception when calling `IDataService` or `IPasswordHasher`... "xyz has been disposed.".

Comment: Cheers (+1 and ans) that looks exactly what I was missing.